# Confuse about android check list box

Tags: android

I would like to implement products list with checklistbox after select radio button.
And I would like to show chekclistbox as dialog box. My product list data come from sqllite.
It is need to implement adapter class to show data for checklistbox or can I directly implement for checklistbox data in alertDialog . Please clear for me.

In mainActivity

```
public RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener setOnCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        rdoPCode = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
        switch (checkedId) {
        case R.id.rdoAll:
            Toast.makeText(context, rdoPCode.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            break;
        case R.id.rdoCustom:
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.context,
                    ProductListChkActivity.class);
            MainActivity.context.startActivity(localIntent);                
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

In ProductListChkActivity

```
public class ProductListChkActivity extends Activity {

private static Button button_selectall;
private static Button button_unselectall;
private static CheckBox chkProductCode;

private static CashSaleProductLogic _sellProductLogic;
public static List<CashSaleProductInfo> _SaleProductInfo;

public static ListView lvlchkPrdlist;
private Button btnSelectAll, btnUnSelectAll;

// For chk productcode
private static ProductListChkAdapter _ProductListChkAdapter;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.productinofchk);

    context = this;

    init();

    ProductCodeChk();
}

private void init() {
    button_selectall = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button_selectall);
    button_unselectall = (Button) this
            .findViewById(R.id.button_unselectall);
    chkProductCode = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.chkProductCode);
    lvlchkPrdlist = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.lvlchkPrdlist);

    _sellProductLogic = new CashSaleProductLogic(this);
    _SaleProductInfo = _sellProductLogic.getAllsellProductDataLogic();
}

protected void ProductCodeChk() {
    try {

        _ProductListChkAdapter = new ProductListChkAdapter(context,
                _SaleProductInfo, 1);
        this.lvlchkPrdlist.setAdapter(_ProductListChkAdapter);      

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}

public void OnClickbillbtncancel(View paramView) {
    MainActivity.textClear();
    Intent localIntent = new Intent(ProductListChkActivity.this,
            MainActivity.class);
    ProductListChkActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
}
```

}

I would like to show productinofchk layout as dialogbox

Comment: You should use custom layout file and inflate in your AlertDialog.

Comment: I don't understand a word of what you're asking. Please structure your post, format it a bit and show what you have already done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go through floating dialogs in android. check out this documentation :

[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: It's **Dialog**, not *dialogues* :)